# How can I use a Pi Zero to detect when a JUUL device is being charged?

Tags: python, pi-zero

I am hoping to monitor my JUUL usage (a bad habit picked up in lockdown) using a Pi Zero. I am hoping to do this by always leaving the device on charge when I am not using it so that I can determine usage by counting the amount of time for which it was not charging.

To do this, I intend to connect a JUUL charger to the Pi (either using the micro usb port or using the GPIO pins; I'm not sure which of these options is preferable).

However, I then need the Pi to be able to detect when the JUUL device is connected to the charger. Does anyone know how this might be done? Is there a way (using Python) to detect the power output of the Pi?

Additionally, when the JUUL is fully charged, will the Pi believe that it is not connected to the charger (if it is determining whether or not the device is connected by using the power output being supplied)?

Answer (score 3):

Unless a device actually communicates on USB, there is no way to know whether it is plugged in or not. The Pi has not built-in equipment to measure the power supply current, or current in a given USB port. And, as you rightfully notice, such measurement wouldn't be a reliable indicator of connection, because once the battery is charged, it stops drawing current despite being connected.

Comment: Thanks, I guess the only option is a small sensor inside the charger then.